# in ableton live 10 where did the crossfade controls on two adjacent clips go?

Tags: ableton-live

In Ableton if you have two clips butted up against each other on the same track, you used t be able to edit the crossfade between them by pulling down the menu on the track controls on the right and choosing Fades.

That seems to have disappeared and though their website sys the default 4ms fade can be edited like a manually created fade, i can't find where it defines exactly how to do that.

So where can I adjust the crossfade between adjacent clips on the same track?

Comment: does this answer your question: https://help.ableton.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000036890-Editing-Fades-in-Live-10  Make sure to turn off Automation Mode in Live 10 in order to view and edit Fades. Fades are not visible when Automation Mode is active.

Comment: That worked though I'd add a quick note that you turn off automation but then hover the cursor over the ends of the clip to reveal the fade handles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, turning off automation will let you hover your cursor over the clip's boundaries and that reveals the fade handles.